# UIView animate finished called before animation finished

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, swift3

I'm trying to create an `animation` where the view first animate down and then gets removed from super view, my code looks like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 5, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
        NSLog("Animation started")
        self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:-500), animated: true)

    }, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
        if finished{
            NSLog("Animation stopped")
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    })
```

As the duration is `5` so the finished should gets called after 5 seconds or I am wrong?

In this case the finished gets called before the animation is finished and removed the view and animation obviously didn't show at all because the view was removed.

Here is the `NSLog`

```
2017-01-02 17:39:37.649 [1581:26706] Animation started
2017-01-02 17:39:37.652 [1581:26706] Animation stopped
```

finished was called in less than a seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `setContentOffset:` function `animated` to `false`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 5, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
    NSLog("Animation started")
    self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0,y:-500), animated: false)
}, completion: {(finished: Bool) in
    if finished{
        NSLog("Animation stopped")
        self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
})
```